# Keyword based text classification

Tags: nlp, text-mining, feature-extraction, text-classification, document-classification

I want to classify some texts based on available keywords in each class. In other words, I have a list of keywords for each category. I need some heuristic methods using these keywords and determine top similar categories for each text. I should say that in the current phase of the project, I didn't want to use a machine learning-based method for text classification.

Comment: You need to be more specific for anyone to be able to answer this question

Comment: I propose a baseline: for each category, just count the number of keywords from this category occuring in the given text, and use the categories with the largest number of occurrences. 
If this baseline doesn't work for you, please explain why. 
In general, when asking questions on SO, it is recommended to give example of code you have tried and to explain why it doesn't satisfy you.